# How to list currently not installed packages?

Tags: command-line, package-management, apt, dpkg

I'd like to output a list of all currently not installed packages (they are visible in Synaptic for example) using only shell commands. How do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be it:

```
aptitude -F %p search '!~i'
```

This will list all packages currently not installed (including virtual packages and packages that have only their configuration files installed). If you don't want virtual packages (that's what Synaptic shows as *Not installed*), extend the search pattern to:

```
aptitude -F %p search '!~i!~v'
```

You probably need to install `aptitude`, as it's no longer part of the default installation as of Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: Thanks, but does not list all (not installed) packages that lists synaptic :(

Comment: @htorque, your line lists all installed packages, not all not-installed packages

Comment: @BonboBingo: see update.

Comment: @Martin Owens -doctormo-: no, it didn't. I asked dpkg to list all packages matching "*" (which I supposed were all packages), then filtered for "^.u", which are all packages currently in the Not-Installed state.

Comment: @htorque - Except dpkg only knows about *installed* or *uninstalled* packages, not *never-installed* packages. See --get-selections for the kind of data dpkg has. You need to use apt-cache to search available packages.

Comment: Reading your comment below: this does NOT include virtual packages (but that's also true for Synaptic, as the package counts are the same). If you want to include virtual packages, you'd just add a 'v' to the grep part: `grep "^[p|c|v]"`

Comment: @htorque - I spent way too much time trying to answer this question. Now I feel like horrible because you got there first. I guess this is why ask is a waste of time.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite follow. :) A lot of questions have more than one right answer - it's up to the community to promote or demote answers by voting (eg., my solution needs an additional package installed, which could be a plus for yours).

Comment: Instead of cutting out the package names afterwards, just have aptitude only display package names in the first place. `aptitude --disable-columns -F %p search !~i`. Alternatively also filter out virtual packages if they're not wanter. `aptitude --disable-columns -F %p search !~i!~v`

Comment: @geirha: D'oh, that makes the whole thing a lot easier. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't fast, but it will work:

```
apt-cache pkgnames | xargs -i1 dpkg-query -f '${Package}\n' --show '1' 2>&1 | perl -lne 'if(/matching (.*)$/){ print $1 }'
```

**Warning:** This prints all packages, even meta-packages and virtual packages.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? It's very odd to find someone who wants to do this who isn't using python. I was also wrong, it does print meta packages (double checked man page)